# How can I create a color variant from a base color in React Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have in my theme a given color constant, let's say '#FFBA60'.

I want to use React Material UI functions to derive from that basic color a few others. (let's say one brighter by 30% and one darker by 10%).

Is there a function for this? (something like in Sass `brighten('#FFBA60,30%)`)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is a darken function in material-ui/styles.

```
import { darken } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const darkenedColor50Percent = darken('#4f4', 0.5);
```

Comment: In MUI V5.14+ use it from `@mui/material/styles`, specially in Next JS to avoid barrel import optimization issue.

Answer (score 11):

The material-ui theme does it on itself, you just need to pass the main color and it calculates the other colors with the main color as a base. Here an example from the docs:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      // light: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      main: '#ff4400',
      // dark: will be calculated from palette.primary.main,
      // contrastText: will be calculated to contrast with palette.primary.main
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#0066ff',
      main: '#0044ff',
      // dark: will be calculated from palette.secondary.main,
      contrastText: '#ffcc00',
    },
    // Used by `getContrastText()` to maximize the contrast between
    // the background and the text.
    contrastThreshold: 3,
    // Used by the functions below to shift a color's luminance by approximately
    // two indexes within its tonal palette.
    // E.g., shift from Red 500 to Red 300 or Red 700.
    tonalOffset: 0.2,
  },
});
```

[Here the documentation link](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/)

If you are trying to generate the colors for a custom property, the `theme.palette.augmentColor()` function, with it you can customise the settings too. Here the link for the [code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/99ca172ffd3c775240e710f647bb7880c328f7c7/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.js#L159) with all attributes that it accept

The [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-theme-variables-2mp0t) example (just passing the main color)

Comment: But if I add another color to the palette it doesn't do it to the new color. And I also want to control the amount to darken or to lighten , specifically for a specific color..

Comment: @Yaron just updated the answer, see if this can help you

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It is not quite what I looked for but inside the code in the link you attached I found exactly what I looked for - a 'darken' function that works exactly like the one in Sass. Thank you !

Answer (score 11):

For MUI v.5

```
import {darken} from "@mui/material/styles";
```

...

```
color: darken(theme.palette.primary.main, 0.125),
```